# Dynamic array if condition met for later usage

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm a beginner so that's a beginners problem.
C++

If the user's choice is == 1 I wish the program would create a dynamic array of  a size that is for user to decide. And that array would later  be used for further actions. If the choice is not == 1 don't create anything.

What I tried:

```
int main()
{

std::cin>>choice;

if (choice==1) 
{
int * size = new int;
std::cin >> *size ;
double *array = new double[*size];
}

return 0;
}
```

However if I put it like this the array doesnt exist outside "if".
How can I get a dynamic array created for further usage if the user's choice is == 1 but only in that case? 
I have run out of ideas.

Comment: You should not be using `new` in this program. For the size, use a normal int variable, not a pointer. For the array, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    int choice;
    cin >> choice;

    vector<int> array;
    if( choice == 1 )
    {
        int size;
        cin >> size;
        array.resize( size );
    }

    // Here you can use array
}
```

Disclaimer: code not checked by compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Put the array outside the scope of your if statement:

```
int main()
{
    int choice;
    std::cin>>choice;
    double *array;

    if (choice==1) 
    {
       int * size = new int;
       std::cin >> *size ;
       array = new double[*size];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, since you are using C++, consider using a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Move your variable declarations outside the block to fix your original question.

```
int main()
{
    double *array = null;

    std::cin>>choice;

    if (choice==1) 
    {
        int * size = new int;
        std::cin >> *size ;
        array = new double[*size];
    }

    // at this point array is ether null or a pointer to a buffer

    return 0;
}
```

Or, more improved

```
int main()
{
    double *array = null;
    int choice;

    std::cin>>choice;

    if (choice==1) 
    {
        std::cin >> choice ;
        array = new double[choice];
    }

    // at this point array is ether == null or a pointer to a buffer

    delete[] array;   <--- don't forget to delete it!
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend using an std::vector : it can be resized easily
Also, you do not need to allocate memory for a pointer

```
int main() {
    int * size;
    std::cin>>choice;
    std::vector<double> myvector;
    if (choice==1) 
    {
        std::cin >> *size ;
        myvector.resize(*size);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/

when using C++ you should rather use containers such as the vectors rather than arrays.
C++ containers come with a lot of very useful functions ( resize is only one of them ).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/

I would also highly recommend checking the value of size before using it as you may end up with unexpected results.

example :

```
*size = 0; // init before the loop
while (*size <= 0)
{
    std::cin >> *size;
    if (*size <= 0) // an error message can be appreciated
    {
        std::cout << "error on size value" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior because you're dereferencing `size` while it is uninitialized.